How do I attach the contents of a failed Airflow task log to the failure notification email message?
I have an Airflow DAG that runs a BashOperator task.  When it fails I get an email with not much detail:
Try 1 out of 1
Exception:
Bash command failed. The command returned a non-zero exit code 1.
Log: Link
Host: 2db56ea2ab34
Mark success: Link

I'm interested in the details that tell me why my task failed, i.e. the errors I see when I click the Log link.  How can I make Airflow attach that log so that the people getting the failure email don't have to click through?  I am still on Airflow 2.6.1 but could upgrade if needed as part of troubleshooting this.  In case it's relevant, the BashOperator is a docker run command -- is that why my attempt below isn't working?  I am aware of DockerOperator but that's a separate matter.
What I tried
I tried writing my own versions of a failure_callback() function and was able to get it sending an email, but it couldn't successfully attach the logs.
import os
import tempfile
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator
from airflow.utils.email import send_email
from airflow.utils.log.logging_mixin import LoggingMixin
from airflow.utils.log.log_reader import TaskLogReader
from datetime import datetime

def failure_callback(context):
    task_instance = context['task_instance']
    log_url = task_instance.log_url
    exception = context.get('exception')

    # Fetch the log content using TaskLogReader
    try:
        log_reader = TaskLogReader()
        log_content, _ = log_reader.read_log_chunks(task_instance, try_number=task_instance.try_number, metadata={})
        log_content = ''.join([chunk['message'] for chunk in log_content[0]])

    except Exception as e:
        log_content = f"Could not fetch log content: {e}"

    subject = f"Airflow Task Failure: {task_instance.task_id}"
    html_content = f"""
    Task: {task_instance.task_id}<br>
    DAG: {task_instance.dag_id}<br>
    Execution Time: {context['logical_date']}<br>
    Log URL: <a href="{log_url}">{log_url}</a><br>
    Exception: {exception}<br>

    """

    # Write log content to a temporary file
    with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False, suffix='.log') as temp_log_file:
        temp_log_file.write(log_content.encode('utf-8'))
        temp_log_file_path = temp_log_file.name

    # Send email with log content as attachment
    send_email(
        to=default_args['email'],
        subject=subject,
        html_content=html_content,
        files=[temp_log_file_path]  # Attach the log file
    )
    os.remove(temp_log_file_path)

I added on_failure_callback=failure_callback to my DAG definition.
The result
An email is sent with an attachment, but the attached just says:

Could not fetch log content: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str

And then when I examine the task logs in the Airflow UI it says:
[2024-08-08, 14:41:09 EDT] {file_task_handler.py:522} ERROR - Could not read served logs
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 1407, in _run_raw_task
    self._execute_task_with_callbacks(context, test_mode)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 1558, in _execute_task_with_callbacks
    result = self._execute_task(context, task_orig)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 1628, in _execute_task
    result = execute_callable(context=context)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/operators/bash.py", line 210, in execute
    raise AirflowException(
airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: Bash command failed. The command returned a non-zero exit code 1.


Good question
I think the best way is override html_content_template. But as I see traceback is unavailable in template variables.
You can create a tiny macros using custom plugin. Here is an example:

Create a new jinja template(airflow_email_html_content_template.jinja2):

<a href="{{ti.log_url}}">{{ti.hostname}} logs</a>.
Try <span style="
  background-color: #dc3545;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: .35em .65em;
  font-size: .75em;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 1;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  border-radius: .25rem;">{{try_number}} out of {{max_tries + 1}}</span>
<a href="{{ti.mark_success_url}}">Mark success</a>
<br/>
<br/>
<b>Exception:</b>
<pre style="
  color: #333;
  padding: 9px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  border: 1px solid #e3e3e3;
  min-height: 20px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.05);
  font-family: Verdana,sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 1.5;
">
    {{ macros.test_plugin.get_exception_trace(exception) }}
</pre>



Create a plugin:

# plugins/test_plugin.py
import traceback

from airflow.plugins_manager import AirflowPlugin


def get_exception_trace(error: Exception):
    """
    call from template: {{ macros.test_plugin.get_exception_trace(exception) }}
    """
    return ''.join(traceback.TracebackException.from_exception(error).format())


class AirflowTestPlugin(AirflowPlugin):
    name = "test_plugin"
    macros = [get_exception_trace]


DAG example:

from datetime import datetime

from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.python import PythonOperator

dag = DAG(
    dag_id='example',
    start_date=datetime(2024, 1, 1),
    schedule_interval=None,
    default_args={
        'email_on_failure': True,
        'email': ['...'],  # set list of emails
    },
    catchup=False,
)


def error(*args, **kwargs):
    raise Exception(kwargs)


PythonOperator(dag=dag, task_id='test_task', python_callable=error)


Configure airflow.cfg settings:

default_email_on_failure = True
html_content_template = {FULL_PATH_TO}/airflow_email_html_content_template.jinja2
plugins_folder = {FULL_PATH_TO}/plugins


Restart airflow, trigger the DAG manually and check email:


You can implement +- the same using on_failure_callback if you interested in file attachments
